# Problem with DOM and selected element of object

Tags: arrays, object, dom, find

I would like to display the property of age and if a person is vaccinated under each name after each button's click, but these properties appear under the page. How can I do it?

Furthermore, which concepts of the dom should I explore in order to build logics where there is a correlation and interaction between dom and objects? (e.g. select an item via the dom and view its details).

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="list-container"></div>
    </div>

    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
```

```
const persons = [
  { name: "carl", age: 20, vaccinated: true, id: 1 },
  { name: "alex", age: 45, vaccinated: false, id: 2 },
  { name: "alice", age: 12, vaccinated: true, id: 3 },
  { name: "erick", age: 2, vaccinated: true, id: 4 },
  { name: "fred", age: 23, vaccinated: false, id: 5 },
  { name: "wandy", age: 13, vaccinated: true, id: 6 },
];

const generalContainer = document.querySelector(".container");
const listContainer = document.querySelector(".list-container");

function renderItems(obj) {
  let dataId;
  let item;
  let sub;
  obj.forEach((element) => {
    item = document.createElement("div");
    let itemAttr = document.createAttribute("data-id");
    itemAttr.value = element.id;
    item.setAttributeNode(itemAttr);
    dataId = item.dataset.id;
    item.innerHTML = `<p>NAME: ${element.name}</p>
    <button class="btn">${element.name}</button>
    <div class='sub'></div>
    
    `;
    sub = document.querySelector(".sub");
    listContainer.appendChild(item);
  });

  let btn = document.querySelectorAll(".btn");
  let selected;
  let subItem = document.createElement("div");
  btn.forEach((el) => {
    el.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      let textValue = el.textContent;
      selected = obj.find((ele) => {
        return ele.name === textValue;
      });
      //subItem = document.createElement("div");
      subItem.innerHTML = `
      <div><p>AGE: ${selected.age}</p>
    <p>VACCINE STATUS: ${
      selected.vaccinated ? "Vaccinated" : "Not vaccinated"
    }</div>`;
      console.log(sub);
      sub.appendChild(subItem);
      item.append(sub);
    });
  });
}

renderItems(persons);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try a more simplified version. Among other things, it uses event delegation for event listeners:

```js
const persons = [{
    name: "carl",
    age: 20,
    vaccinated: true,
    id: 1
  },
  {
    name: "alex",
    age: 45,
    vaccinated: false,
    id: 2
  },
  {
    name: "alice",
    age: 12,
    vaccinated: true,
    id: 3
  },
  {
    name: "erick",
    age: 2,
    vaccinated: true,
    id: 4
  },
  {
    name: "fred",
    age: 23,
    vaccinated: false,
    id: 5
  },
  {
    name: "wandy",
    age: 13,
    vaccinated: true,
    id: 6
  }
];

let listContainer = document.querySelector(".list-container");

function renderItems(obj) {
  obj.forEach((element) => {
    new_elem = `
    <div data-id="${element.id}"> 
       <p>NAME: ${element.name}</p>
       <button but-id="${element.id}">${element.name}</button>
       <div class='sub'></div> 
    </div>
    `;
    listContainer.insertAdjacentHTML("afterbegin", new_elem);
  });

  listContainer.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    person = e.target.getAttribute("but-id");
    p_name = e.target.innerText;

    dest = document.querySelector(`div[data-id="${person}"]  div.sub`);

    let selected = persons.find(({name}) => name === p_name);
    subItem = `
     <div>
              <p>AGE: ${selected.age}</p>  
               <p>VACCINE STATUS: ${
      selected.vaccinated ? "Vaccinated" : "Not vaccinated"
             }</p>  
     </div>
    `;
    dest.innerHTML = subItem;
  });
}

renderItems(persons);
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="list-container"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```